# python Метки в массиве numpy

Tags: python, массивы, numpy

Вопрос по сортировке данных для обучения нейросети. Распознавание цифр из набора MNIST.

Как отсортировать эти данные, чтобы получить три разные группы и три разные сети соответственно и потом обучить каждую сеть отдельно?

Есть массив `numpy array` из цифр `0,1, ...9`. По определённым условиям поставлены метки внутри массива  `y`. Как обращаться к этим меткам `0,1,2`?

Загружаем массив из MNIST для распознавания. Группы цифр 3:

- 0 группа - `1,2,4,9,8`.
- 1 группа - `6,0`.
- 2 группа - `3,5,7`.

Загружаем MNIST:

```
  (x_train_org, y_train_org), (x_test_org, y_test_org) = mnist.load_data()
```

Затем

```
y = y_train_org
 y[(y == 1) | (y == 2) | (y == 4) | (y == 9) | (y == 8)] = 0
y[(y == 6) | (y == 0)] = 1
y[(y == 3) | (y == 5) | (y == 7)] = 2
```

Привязываем данные (ставим метки)

```
y[y == 0]
y[y == 1]
y[y == 2]
```

Как эти данные сопоставить с x_train и отдать на обучение сети, чтобы распознать цифры внутри каждой группы отдельно?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе небольшой, но воспроизводимый пример входных данных и то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)

Comment: Что значит: `"По определенным условиям поставлены метки внутри массива y"`?

Comment: Более развернутый вопрос задан с примером кода здесь https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1023311/%d0%94%d0%b0%d0%b9%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%81%d1%81%d1%8b%d0%bb%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b7%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%bb%d1%8f-x-test-y-test-x-train-y-train/1023326?noredirect=1#comment1740166_1023326