# Дайте ссылки про срезы для x test, y test, x train, y train

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, нейронные-сети, numpy

Если надо сгруппировать dataset на  x test, y test, x train, y train ИЛИ готовый x test разделить на разные подгруппы одновременно с y test, чтобы потом их отдельно обучать. Не нашла ресурсов никаких.
Пример нарезки  x test, y test, x train, y train для https://machinelearningmastery.com/index-slice-reshape-numpy-arrays-machine-learning-python/ 
У меня трудности в том, что надо разгруппировать x test, от которого зависит y test. Например есть dataset из 2 колонок age(возраст) и gender(пол) - это x test, и есть колонка y test genre (предпочтения). Сеть обучили и в зависимости от возраста и пола она предсказывает предпочтения из genre. А теперь надо x test разделить на подгруппы для возраста меньше 18 и старше 18 и отдельно эти подруппы обучить, чтобы ускорить работу сети например или по другим причинам, не суть. Но тогда надо делить и y test на две подргуппы. А как?

Пробую так.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
# создаем таблицу общую для X и Y
data = np.array([[5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 45],
                   ['1', '0', '0', '1', '1', '0'], 
                   ['мультики', 'куклы', 'дискотеки', 'учеба', 'работа', 'дача']])

names = pd.DataFrame(data.T, columns = ['age', 'gender', 'genre'])
names["age"] = pd.to_numeric(names["age"], errors="coerce")
Y = pd.DataFrame(names, columns = ['genre'])
X = pd.DataFrame(names, columns = ['age', 'gender'])
mask = (names['age'] < 18) == 0
Xtest1, Xtest2 = names[mask], names[~mask]
```

А Y куда тут прицепить?

Comment: Я ничего не понял. Попробуйте переформулировать вопрос. Было бы идеально добавить парочку примеров

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Создайте булевую маску по которой можно выбрать подвыборку данных. Далее используйте данную маску для выбора данных как из `X` так и из `y`:

```
In [52]: mask = X["age"] < 18

In [53]: X1 = X[mask]

In [54]: X2 = X[~mask]

In [55]: Y1 = Y[mask]

In [56]: Y2 = Y[~mask]
```

---

```
In [57]: X1
Out[57]:
   age gender
0    5      1
1   10      0
2   15      0

In [58]: Y1
Out[58]:
       genre
0   мультики
1      куклы
2  дискотеки

In [59]: X2
Out[59]:
   age gender
3   20      1
4   25      1
5   45      0

In [60]: Y2
Out[60]:
    genre
3   учеба
4  работа
5    дача
```

---

булевая маска это набор логических значений (длина маски должна совпадать с числом строк DataFrame), при помощи которого удобно фильтровать / выбирать данные:

```
In [64]: idx
Out[64]:
0     True
1     True
2     True
3    False
4    False
5    False
Name: age, dtype: bool

In [65]: ~idx
Out[65]:
0    False
1    False
2    False
3     True
4     True
5     True
Name: age, dtype: bool
```

Comment: С индексами непонятно

Comment: Спасибо, две недели по всем видосикам вникала

Comment: Вы бы смогли сэкономить себе недельку, если бы сразу задали вопрос на SO с примером входных и, особенно, выходных (те, которые хотите получить) данных ;)

Comment: А индексы - это та же маска?

Comment: Вот задавала, но не знала как задать правильно https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1015579/python-%d0%9c%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b5-numpy?noredirect=1#comment1725051_1015579

Comment: @svil, а по ссылке в комментарии вопрос/ответ читали? :)

Comment: Читала, сейчас только вникла и спросила, а так тупила долго, пока знакомилась с python

Comment: Про индексы в начале писали, если это не маска, а другой способ сделать задачу, дайте ссылку почитать про эти индексы

Comment: @svil, https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html